# Python, divide string into several substrings

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a string of RNA i.e:

```
AUGGCCAUA
```

I would like to generate all substrings by the following way:

```
#starting from 0 character
AUG, GCC, AUA
#starting from 1 character
UGG, CCA
#starting from 2 character
GGC, CAU
```

I wrote a code that solves the first sub-problem:

```
for i in range(0,len(rna)):
  if fmod(i,3)==0:
    print rna[i:i+3]
```

I have tried to change the starting position i.e.:

```
 for i in range(1,len(rna)):
```

But it produces me the incorrect results:

```
 GCC, UA #instead of UGG, CCA
```

Could you please give me a hint where is my mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are always extracting substring from the index which is divisible by 3. Instead, try this

```
a = 'AUGGCCAUA'
def getSubStrings(RNA, position):
    return [RNA[i:i+3] for i in range(position, len(RNA) - 2, 3)]

print getSubStrings(a, 0)
print getSubStrings(a, 1)
print getSubStrings(a, 2)
```

**Output**

```
['AUG', 'GCC', 'AUA']
['UGG', 'CCA']
['GGC', 'CAU']
```

**Explanation**

`range(position, len(RNA) - 2, 3)` will generate a list of numbers with common difference 3, starting from the `position` till the length of the list - 2. For example,

```
print range(1, 8, 3)
```

`1` is the starting number, `8` is the last number, `3` is the common difference and it will give

```
[1, 4, 7]
```

These are our starting indices. And then we use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate the new list like this

```
[RNA[i:i+3] for i in range(position, len(RNA) - 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is this, I was looking for. Could you clarify, what does the following mean:                         range(position, len(RNA) - 2, 3)

Comment: @mr.M Please check my answer now, I added little explanation

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
for i in range(len(rna)):
    if rna[i+3:]:
        print(rna[i:i+3])
```

outputs:

```
AUG
UGG
GGC
GCC
CCA
CAU
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought of this oneliner:

```
a = 'AUGGCCAUA'
[a[x:x+3] for x in range(len(a))][:-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def generate(str, index):
    for i in range(index, len(str), 3):
        if len(str[i:i+3]) == 3:
            print str[i:i+3]
```

Example:

```
In [29]: generate(str, 1)
UGG
CCA

In [30]: generate(str, 0)
AUG
GCC
AUA
```